# Android emulator doesn't scroll back UP

Tags: android, eclipse, scroll, emulation

Trying to use the AVD in Eclipse Kepler on Windows 7 Pro.
Nexus 7 2012 with the Level 19 (4.4.2) APIs and the Intel Atom processor.

Every listview, once scrolled down, immediately scrolls to the bottom and stays there.  I can start to drag the list back towards the top, but as soon as I let up on the mouse button, it bounces back to the bottom of the list.  This is for ANY list - system settings, app listings, etc., as well as my custom coded HTML5 app.

Has anybody ever seen that before?  A Google search turned up nothing useful...

-Paul-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue follow the steps below:

1. Click on virtual device manager and then select the AVD that you are using.
2. Now, click on edit and choose CPU/ABI as ARM.
3. Click ok and and run your project again. The scroll view will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - solved it by changing the Virtual Device to use ARM CPU instead of Intel Atom

(Change under Run -> Run Configurations -> Target -> Your virtual device -> Manager.. -> Your device -> Edit... -> CPU/ABI: Change to ARM)